# How to handle functions with multiple outputs when also limiting line lengths - python style guide

Tags: python, pep8

I sometimes find myself building functions that return multiple variables. And when I want to use such a function, I almost always tend to break the style guide on line length. I have tried a few ways on fixing this issue, but I have not yet been able to decide if any of them are good.

Just to be clear, this is a kind of function that I'm talking about:

```py
def some_func():
    # some code
    return var_1, var_2, ..., var_n
```

And this is the straight-forward approach whan calling such a function:

```py
var_1, var_2, ..., var_n = some_func()
```

*This tend to break the style guide line length.*

Some ways of 'fixing' this:

Alt 1:

```py
(var_1,
 var_2,
 ...,
 var_n) = some_func()
```

Alt 2:

```py
all_vars = some_func()

var_1 = all_vars[0]
var_2 = all_vars[1]
...
var_n = all_vars[n-1]
```

But I don't really find any of them satisfactory.

What do the community say abut this? Which is better? Are they both good, but in different situations? Is it only a matter of taste? Is there other, better, alternatives?

Comment: The second solution may be error prone because it's fairly simple to mistype an index of the list (moreover, `some_func()` may return an arbitrary iterator which may not support indexing at all) or accidentally not use one of them at all, while the first solution unpacks all the values automatically and errors out if the number of variables doesn't exactly match the number of values returned.

Comment: Do you need always **all** variables from the function?, if not, you maybe can use asterisk notation `var1, var2, *rest = some_func()`

Comment: what about returning a dictionary? `res['var_x'] = var_x`

Comment: I think this question is opinion-based. You might post your full code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com to see how it could be refactored for your specific case.

Comment: @AndrejKesely, at the moment I know that I will at least use enough variables to make it messy. I didn't know about `*`-notation, and I will make sure to use it whenever I can, as well as `_` to silently ignore one or more variables.